# How can I store and update multiple values in React useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've a series of user data elements which I'm collecting inside a React component using hooks.

```
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
```

Each of these are updated as follows.

```
<input type="text"
       className="form-control"
       id="mobile"
       placeholder="Enter a valid mobile number"
       onChange={event => {setMobile(event.target.value)}}/>
```

Is there a more succint way to do this using an object as the variable?

Comment: Sure, you could... use an object as the variable. `const [values, setValues] = useState({ mobile: "", ... });`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do I call the set methods, inside the individual `onChange` events.

Comment: `setValues({ ...values, [prop]: newValue });`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You should add `name` attributes to input tags. Each name must refer to key in `AllValues` object.

```
const [allValues, setAllValues] = useState({
   mobile: '',
   username: '',
   email: '',
   password: '',
   confirmPassword: ''
});
const changeHandler = e => {
   setAllValues({...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
return (
   <input type="text"
       className="form-control"
       id="mobile"
       name="mobile"
       placeholder="Enter a valid mobile number"
       onChange={changeHandler}
   />
   // ...
)
```

Comment: I did not realize why `[e.target.name]` has to be inside `[]`?

Comment: This is the way to add object key by variable (e.target.name) name.

Comment: why should we use the name instead of the id? Convention only?

Comment: because ID has to be unique, but multiple elements can have same names.

Comment: `TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Answer (score 23):

The above answer could create issues in some cases, the following should be the right approach.

```
const [allValues, setAllValues] = useState({
   mobile: '',
   username: '',
   email: '',
   password: '',
   confirmPassword: ''
});
const changeHandler = e => {
   setAllValues( prevValues => {
   return { ...prevValues,[e.target.name]: e.target.value}
}
}
```

Comment: This should be safe more than the accepted answer. I have experienced some tricky bugs and this answer solved that problem.

Comment: For React 16 and earlier, this might cause a problem because of Event Pooling. Be sure to use this only for React 17 or later. Note that you can still use this answer with some additional lines like <_name=e.target.name;_value=e.target.value> and using _name and _value instead of using e directly in the return phrase.

Answer (score 7):

> Set initial values

```
const initialValues = {                   // type all the fields you need
name: '',
email: '',
password: ''
};
```

> UseState

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);       // set initial state
```

> Handling the changes

```
const handleChange = (e) => {                
  setValues({
    ...values,                                // spreading the unchanged values
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,          // changing the state of *changed value*
  });
};
```

> Making the Form

```
<form>
  <input type="email"
   id="xyz"
   name="email"                                     // using name, value, onChange for applying changes
   value={email}
   onChange={changeHandler}
   placeholder="Enter your email"
   />
   // other inputs
</form>
```