# Change Textinput value when rendering Using .map() React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, array-map

i am using map function to render my component which have textInput . I want to change value of textInput using onchangeText function.

```
 //main component
 const [Value0, setValue0] = useState('');
 const [Value1, setValue1] = useState('');
 const [Value2, setValue2] = useState('');
 ..
   const handleOnSubmit = () => { //fired when click from this 
  compnent button
console.log(Value0,"Value0");
 console.log(Value1,"Value1");
}
 //in my return i use :
   {
        data.map((item, id) => {
          return (
            <ViewDeatilCard1 key={id}  /> //data having length 4

          )
        })
      }
                 <ViewDeatilCard1 key={id} setChangeText={(value)=>{`'setValue${id}${(value)}'`}} /> //this
                 <ViewDeatilCard1 key={id} setChangeText={()=>{`'setValue${id}'`}} /> //this
                 <ViewDeatilCard1 key={id} setChangeText={`'setValue${id}'`} /> //this
  // none of this work
 // in my component i use 
 export const ViewDeatilCard1 = ({
setChangeText
 }) => {
console.log(setChangeText,"setChangeText");
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        
            <View style={styles.body}>
            <FormInput
             style={styles.bodyText}
     
       labelText="Enter pick up loaction"
        iconName="null"
        onChangeText={setChangeText}
      />
            </View>
        </View>
    
)}
```

how can i change my  value using this approach

Comment: Should each  <ViewDeatilCard1 />. have its own state ?

Comment: Its kinda hard to make out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, I am rendering 4 <ViewDeatilCard1 /> right now and want to have all 4 state and when click from main component their updated states will log.

Comment: Id look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813926/usestate-to-update-multiple-values-in-react