# How can I combine multiple state values into one useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
function Nav(){

   const [toggleDropDownAbout, setToggleDropDownAbout] = useState(fasle);
   const [toggleDropDownCareers, setToggleDropDownCareers] = useState(fasle);
   const [toggleDropDownNew, setToggleDropDownNew] = useState(fasle);

  return(
  
    <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>About Us <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleDropDownAbout &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }
      
      <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>Careers <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleDropDownCareers &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }
      
      <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>Whats new <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleDropDownNew &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }
  
  )
}
```

It's running but is there a way to use one useState or some other way to get the same result. I just dont think this code is good and i dont have any idea how to do this in other way

Comment: If they are all controlled independently, this is fine. If only one is visible at a time, you could combine them into a single state. (Also you have a typo in your initial state values: `fasle` should be `false`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState to update multiple values in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813926/usestate-to-update-multiple-values-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useState` allows you to declare an object as a value too. You can leverage that to define a single state.

```
function Nav(){

   const [toggleStates, setToggleStates] = useState({
       toggleDropDownAbout,
       toggleDropDownCareers,
       toggleDropDownNew
   });
   

  return(
  
    <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>About Us <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleStates.toggleDropDownAbout &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }
      
      <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>Careers <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleStates.toggleDropDownCareers &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }
      
      <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>Whats new <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleStates.toggleDropDownNew &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }
  
  )
}
```

However when using the above approach you need to be mindful that updates using `setToggleStates` will overwrite the entire state value and not merge it. So you should spread and update the object like

```
setToggleState(prev => ({
   ...prev,
   toggleDropDownAbout: !prev.toggleDropDownAbout
}));
```

**P.S.** There is nothing wrong with keeping multiple states with `useState` in your component. Ideally, you should consider creating a single state with a value as object if the states are related and belong to a single property

---

Also depending on interaction, you can simplify the above code. In case your intention is to only open one dropdown at a time, you can store the id enum of the dropdown as state value and use it.

```
function Nav(){

   const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(null);


  return(

    <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>About Us <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleState === 'about' &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }

      <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>Careers <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleState === 'careers' &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }

      <Link to='/' className='flex items-center text-slate-500 font-medium text-base px-3 py-3 nav-item hover:text-red-700 relative gap-1 '>Whats new <FaCaretDown className='rotate'/></Link>
     {toggleState === 'new' &&
      <ul className='grid pl-6 dropdown-item bg-red-100 lg:absolute top-12 z-10'>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>History</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Quality Policy</Link>
        <Link to='/' className='text-slate-500 hover:text-red-700 text-base'>Vision / Mission</Link>
       </ul>
      }

  )
}
```

and update using

```
const toggleDropdown = (id) => {
   setToggleState(prev=> {
       if(prev === id) {
         // close the opened dropdown
         return null;
       }     
       return id;
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Shubham Khatri's answer, after writing

```js
  const [toggleStates, setToggleStates] = useState({
       toggleDropDownAbout,
       toggleDropDownCareers,
       toggleDropDownNew
   });
```

you can destructure them to use them to avoid `toggleStates.XX` like so

```js
const {toggleDropDownAbout, toggleDropDownCareers, toggleDropDownNew} = toggleStates;
```